# Graphviz dot: How to distribute elements evenly?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I prepared this minimal example (you can try it at [http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/ - not okay](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20mydigraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%22a%22-%3E%22d%22%0A%20%20%22b%22-%3E%22e%22%0A%20%20%22b%22-%3E%22f%22%0A%20%20%22c%22-%3E%22g%22%0A%7D%0A)):

```
digraph mydigraph {
  "a"->"d"
  "b"->"e"
  "b"->"f"
  "c"->"g"
}
```

How can I have the elements in the first row (a, b, c) be distributed evenly? ... and the ones in the second row (d, e, f, g) of course as well?

**I tried** changing the order of the elements: It is fine, if the two-node elements follow each other (for example [http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/ - okay](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20mydigraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%22a%22-%3E%22d%22%0A%20%20%22c%22-%3E%22g%22%0A%20%20%22b%22-%3E%22e%22%0A%20%20%22b%22-%3E%22f%22%0A%7D%0A)).

**My assumption**: The uneven distribution seems to happen only when the three-node element is in the middle. (Yes, I cannot work around the problem by changing the order ...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee of symmetry except by explicitly positioning nodes (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords).

However, putting the three troublesome nodes in a cluster produces this for your minimal example

```
digraph mydigraph {
  "a"->"d"
  "b"->"e"
  "b"->"f"
  "c"->"g"
  subgraph clusterX{
    peripheries=0  // do not draw box around cluster
    a b c 
  }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Wow, what a fast and clever answer. Thank you so much, this would fix my minimal example!

This made me aware, that my minimal example was not good enough: http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20mydigraph%20%7B%0A%20%20a-%3Ed%0A%20%20b-%3Ee%0A%20%20b-%3Ef%0A%20%20r-%3Es%0A%20%20r-%3Et%0A%20%20r-%3Eu%0A%20%20r-%3Ev%0A%20%20c-%3Eg%0A%20%20subgraph%20clusterX%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20peripheries%3D0%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20not%20draw%20box%20around%20cluster%0A%20%20%20%20a%20b%20c%20r%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D is more realistic, and here c and g are a bit far away already.

Answer (score 0):

For a more complex graph, "rotate" the clusters (go vertical)

```
digraph mydigraph {
  a->d
  b->e
  b->f
  r->s
  r->t
  r->u
  r->v
  c->g
  subgraph clusterXa {
    peripheries=0  // do not draw box around cluster
    a d
  }
  subgraph clusterXb {
    peripheries=0  // do not draw box around cluster
    b e f
  }
  subgraph clusterXr {
    peripheries=0  // do not draw box around cluster
    c g
  }
  subgraph clusterXc {
    peripheries=0  // do not draw box around cluster
    r s t u v
  }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Yesss, that's it. This works for my real case as well: rankdir=TB, shape=box, ... You are my hero! Thank you so much. I spent so many tries before.